# Evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty }\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^x\:f\left(t\right)dt$ and a big mistake in the book

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

We have to evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty }\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^x\:f\left(t\right)dt$ where $f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{\left(1+t^2\right)\left(1+t^3\right)}$.

In my book they say that $\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^1\:f\left(t\right)dt=\int _1^x\:t^3\cdot f\left(t\right)dt$ to split $\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^x\:f\left(t\right)dt=\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^1\:f\left(t\right)dt+\int _1^x\:f\left(t\right)dt=\int _1^x\:\left(t^3+1\right)f\left(t\right)dt$ which is equal with $\frac{\pi }{4}$.

The big problem is that in my recent post I found that $\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^1\:f\left(t\right)dt$ is not equal with $\int _1^x\:t^3\cdot f\left(t\right)dt$, so what can I do?

Comment: For **this specific** $f$, the relation holds. It does not generally hold, but here it does.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't understand why $\int _1^x\:\frac{1}{t^2}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt=\int _1^x\:t^3\cdot f\left(t\right)dt$, can you explain me?

Comment: Because _for this function_ we have $\frac{1}{t^2} f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) = t^3 f(t)$. Write down the left hand side, and try to transform it into the right hand side. Knowing where you want to end up, you should find the steps.

Comment: Now I understand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $x>1$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{1/x}^{x}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(1+t^3)}&=&\int_{1/x}^{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(1+t^3)}+\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(1+t^3)}\\&=&\int_{1}^{x}\frac{u^3 du}{(1+u^2)(1+u^3)}+\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(1+t^3)}\\&=&\int_{1}^{x}\frac{(1+t^3)\,dt}{(1+t^2)(1+t^3)}\\&=&\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\xrightarrow[x\to +\infty]{}\arctan 1=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
We just used the substitution $t=\frac{1}{u}$, from which $dt=-\frac{du}{u^2}$, in the second step.

So, there is no mistake in your book.

Comment: okay but after substitution I obtain that $\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^1\:f\left(t\right)dt=\int _1^x\:\frac{1}{t^2}\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt$ and why this is equal with $\int _1^x\:t^3\cdot f\left(t\right)dt$  ?

Comment: @Lucas: compute $f(1/t)$.

Comment: now I understand